# How to merge workbooks in openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have several very specifically formatted xlsx files, the formatting would be very laborious to replicate if i loaded these files as data frames. Example being, data in the same column that is both character and numeric. I need to combine these workbooks into one, where each file is a tab.

If I load these workbooks, I can see the structure and styles.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to write multiple workbook objects to a file.  I've seen some mention of using `getStyles()` and `addStyles()`/`replaceStyles()` but no concrete examples.

Any help in either merging workbooks or replicating style for an entire sheet is greatly appreciated.

```
fls <- c('/someplace/file1.xlsx','/someplace/file1.xlsx','/someplace/file1.xlsx')

wbs <- lapply(fls,function(x) openxlsx::loadWorkbook(x))

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "test1") 

writeData(wb, sheet = 'test1', wbs[[1]]$worksheets[[1]], rowNames = TRUE)
```

Comment: For this task, in your normal workflow are you creating the ```xlsx``` files with ```openxlsx```, or must they only be loaded into R (like you've shown in the example)?

Comment: They are loaded into R via loadWorkbook().  If I could do this in Windows, it is a little easier as I could create a COM object, but that is not possible in my case.  It also seems that cloneWorksheet from openxlsx should work, but based on other user comments it is only working within the same workbook currently.  I suppose i could possibly scrape all the cell formats, read.xlsx() into a data frame, and then apply formats cell by cell to the dataframe for writing to a new workbook, file by file.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm interested in the same goal. But my solution is to create all the excel tabs with openxlsx and keep assigning them to the same workbook. I think it's also possible to use VBA inside of Excel to merge all the xlsx files in a directory.

Comment: VBA is absolutely an option, but not in a LInux deployment of R.  At least in my experience.  I've done this with win32com in python as well, but again that requires Windows.   There are several open threads in the openxlsx repo regarding this, one is a change to cloneWorksheet() that looks promising, but nothing committed yet.